# How to code a Netty client to connect to a Signalr hub?

Tags: java, websocket, signalr, netty

I am trying to create a client to receive streaming data from a third party Signalr hub. Currently we use the Netty framework for some other websocket streams so it would be good if I could adapt this to work with a Signalr hub.

The hub exposes a subscription function as well as two invocable functions.

What are the differences between a normal Netty websocket client and a Netty client for a Signalr hub if any?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Netty WebSockets and SignalR are two separate frameworks to that you can use to pass messages through WebSockets.

Using WebSockets directly is not easy and you will have to write a lot of additional codes to address different practical issues. Using the APIs given by one above frameworks is a way to address these.
Since these are two different frameworks, they are not supporting communicating each other.

In your case, Netty client will not connect with Signalr hub.
***The only option is using a Signalr client for that specific programming language***. In your case use the SignalR client for Java.